# How do I make sure a git commit to a non-master branch is not also accidentally to the master branch?

Tags: git, version-control, repository

I initialized a git repo and wanted to put everything in the dev branch only, not also in the master branch, so I used this command sequence:

```
$git checkout -b dev
$git add .
$git commit -m [I added a string message]
```

At that point git log showed the HEAD was at dev.

Then I tried to return to the master branch with this:

```
$git checkout master
```

But I got the error that "master" was not recognized, so I did this:

```
$git checkout -b master
```

And now the log shows the head is at both dev and master.

When I do:`$git ls-tree -r --name-only master` I get all of my files showing up same as when I do it with dev.

How did I screw up, and how can I make sure my files are not committed to the master branch, only to the dev branch?

Answer (score 1):

This is all perfectly normal.  There's really nothing to do about it (well, other than "get used to this kind of thing in Git").

#### Long description of why this is normal and what it all means

> I initialized a git repo ...

Let's be really clear here.  I assume you did this, or something sufficiently equivalent:

```
$ mkdir newrepo
$ cd newrepo
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in ...
```

If this is the case, you're in an interesting situation:

```
$ git status
On branch master

No commits yet

nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)
$ git branch
$
```

That is, while you're `on branch master` as `git status` says, branch `master` doesn't actually *exist!*  You're on a branch that isn't a branch yet!

> so I used this command sequence:
>
> ```
> $ git checkout -b dev
> $ git add .
> $ git commit -m "some message..."
> ```

This is all fine, but let's take a look at what happens after the `git checkout -b`:

```
$ git checkout -b dev
Switched to a new branch 'dev'
$ git status
On branch dev

No commits yet

nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)
$ git branch
$
```

The only thing that has changed, in other words, is that we've gone from being on the branch `master` that doesn't exist, to being on the branch `dev` that doesn't exist.

Now we add some files to the repository and commit, and we see this output (mine will differ somewhat from yours for various reasons):

```
$ echo example > README
$ git add README
$ git commit -m initial
[dev (root-commit) 8ab55c8] initial
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 README
$
```

At this point the outputs from `git status` and `git branch` change:

```
$ git status
On branch dev
nothing to commit, working tree clean
$ git branch
* dev
$
```

Since this Git is reasonably modern, `git status` has switched from the (newish) `No commits yet` output for a new-and-empty repo to the more typical `nothing to commit, working tree clean` message that Git has used since Git 1.6 if not earlier (though there have been slight wording changes over time).  We are on branch `dev` and branch `dev` exists.  If we use a so-called plumbing command, we can see which hash ID the name `dev` identifies:

```
$ git rev-parse dev
8ab55c84b79cad21440187b4f95ce7c3b947064b
```

which is the long version of what we saw in the `git commit` output, when it said:

```
[dev (root-commit) 8ab55c8]
```

which tells us that we just created a new commit, that the new commit is specifically a *root* commit (has no parent), that the abbreviated hash ID of this new commit is `8ab55c8`, and that the new commit resulted in updating—or in this case, *creating*—the branch name `dev`.

#### Branch names contain hash IDs

A branch name, in Git at least, is just a human-readable name for a hash ID, with one other special property.  It's the hash ID, not the name, that locates the commit: the *name* serves to find the hash ID.  In a rather real sense, the hash ID *is* the commit; there's just some data *associated with* that hash ID, which we can see here:

```
$ git cat-file -p 8ab55c8 | sed 's/@/ /'
tree 5c7082135e61da9ffc72ae2cd7d29fe702315004
author Chris Torek <chris.torek gmail.com> 1517087854 -0800
committer Chris Torek <chris.torek gmail.com> 1517087854 -0800

initial
```

This data gives us—or rather Git—everything Git needs to find the files that go with the commit (through a slightly long and twisty process):

```
$ git cat-file -p 5c70821
100644 blob 33a9488b167e4391ad6297a1e43e56f7ec8a294e    README
$ git cat-file -p 33a9488
example
```

but the key here is that everything works by hash ID; the name `dev` just serves to locate the first—or perhaps we should say *last*—hash ID.  (Git likes to work backwards: everything is the last or latest, and from there we find earlier things if needed.  That's not only more convenient for how we *use* Git, it's also *required* because of the fact that everything, once stored, is completely read-only.)

Adding a *new* commit consists of writing out the commit (which requires first gathering its data and writing out its tree), then making the current branch name point to the new commit.  The new commit, once created, contains the hash ID of the commit that *was* the tip of the branch.  (The new commit's hash ID is created on the spot, *from* all the data that go into the new commit.)  This is the other special feature of branch names: when you're "on" one particular branch, adding a new commit tells Git to write the new commit's hash ID into the branch name.

#### This means that for a branch name to exist, it must contain a hash ID

At this point you tried to do `git checkout master`, but *there is no branch named master*.  So you ran instead:

> ```
> git checkout -b master
> ```

which tells Git to go ahead and *create* the name `master`, pointing to the current commit.

The current commit is the (one, single) commit in the repository, and the name `dev` already points to that one commit.  So now you have two branch names, `dev` and `master`, that *both* point to that one commit:

```
o   <-- dev, master (HEAD)
```

The `git checkout` part switches Git's idea of "which branch is the current branch" to be `master`.  The *commit* already exists; the *branch name* is new (created by `-b`); and `HEAD` is now attached to the new branch name.

If you make a new commit right now, Git will construct the new commit, which gets a new hash ID, so that the new commit remembers—"points back to"—the current commit.  It will then write the new commit's hash ID into `master`:

```
o   <-- dev
 \
  o   <-- master (HEAD)
```

and now there will be two commits on `master` and one on `dev`.

To merge branches (later), the two branches *should* have some commit(s) in common.  Modern Git won't merge unrelated branches without `--allow-unrelated-histories`.  Merging unrelated histories can be a little bit tricky, too; it's not something you would want to do as your first merge.  Old versions of Git will merge unrelated histories (which are still slightly tricky to *create*) without warning.  So although it's possible, it's not something you should be doing.

Comment: Thank you so much for that explanation! I was having a lot of trouble finding an explanation I can understand, partly from not knowing what terms to google. But it sounds like it's not safe for me to remove the files that are in master, from master, so they're only in dev.

Comment: @MickeyLater: it's best to think about this in terms of *commits* (rather than files or branches). What goes into *this* commit? What do you want to be in the *next* commit? When you eventually run `git merge`, it works on the basis of commits. Branch names are mainly there to help you remember the raw commit hash IDs that are otherwise impenetrable and useless (at least, to humans).

Comment: Commit 1 has added and updated files on the dev branch, but I checked and it left the master branch unchanged., Commit 2 removed unwanted files from the master branch, and I checked that it did nothing to dev. I know I'm still bringing up branches but can't see how to avoid it.

Comment: Your original question didn't mention a second commit. Once you add the second commit, you'll update one of the two branch names to point to the new commit. The contents of the new commit will be whatever was in the index at the time you ran `git commit`. If you later run `git merge` and it needs to do a full merge, Git will find the *merge base* commit, and (in effect) run two `git diff` commands. If one diff sees "files deleted" and the other diff sees "no change to these files", Git will combine the two changes by deleting the files in the merge result (which may be what you want).

Answer (score 0):

First, explain why it’s the situation you met.

1. Why did master branch not recongized when you use `git checkout master` for the first time

   When you initialized a git repo, the default branch name is `master`, and there hasn’t any versions (commits) on `master` branch. Instead of committing changes on `master` branch, you switched to `dev` branch (`git checkout -b dev`) and committed  changes on `dev` branch. That means discard `master` branch and use `dev` branch instead and commit change on `dev` branch. If you use `git branch`, it only list `dev` branch at that time.
2. Why does `master` show the same with `dev` branch

   When you execute the command `git checkout -b master` on `dev` branch, git will create the new branch `master` from where the `HEAD` (on `dev` branch) is, and then switch `HEAD` to the new created branch `master`. So `master` will also point to the commit which you committed on `dev` branch.

And for most case, branches usually have the same ancestor(s). If you do not want `master` branch has the same ancestor with `dev` branch, you can change `master` branch as an **orphan branch** (unrelated histories with `dev` branch):

```
git checkout dev
git branch -D master
git checkout --orphan master
# make changes as you need
git add .
git commit -m 'commit changes on master branch'
```